# How to get AJAX to post on second page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is what is happening: I send data but and I have it coded to echo out on second page. However, it just echoes out on first page. How do I make it so it echoes out on second page not the first page?

The code on second page executes but it executes on first page. I want it on second page.

```
<!doctype html> FIRST PAGE
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-grn" id="scaleButton">Button</a></div>
<input class="form-control" name="cartID" id="cartID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $order['clientid'] ;?>">
    <p id="edit_box"></p>
<script>
    
$("#scaleButton").click(function()  { 
var cartID = "hello"
var second = "second";
    
///////// AJAX //////// AJAX //////////
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'user/testing1234.php',
        data: {first:cartID,second:second},
        success: function( response ){
            alert('ajax');
            $('#edit_box').html(response);//this is where you populate your response
        }//close succss params
    });//close ajax
///////// AJAX //////// AJAX //////////
})
</script>


</body>
</html>


SECOND PAGE
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$first = $_POST['first'];
$second = $_POST['second'];
$third = $_POST['third'];


echo $second;
echo $second;
echo $second;
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then don't use AJAX. Simply use `<form>` to send your data to second page, and have them displayed there.

Comment: yes I agree with @RajdeepPaul , create a hidden form and give action as second.php and on button click submit this hidden form

Comment: If i use a form and submit button to send data it just submits it and sends the user to second page. I dont wanna send user anywhere. I just want to send the data.

Comment: As [Mike says on your duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41903106/472495), readers will need to know more about the first and second pages. Who are the users of those pages - do you have one user viewing each one?

Comment: Okay, so really basic. all i wanna do is pass a variable one page to the next without being sent to the page i am sending data too. Does that make sense? Like data could be just the number 1 and all i wanna do is send that 1 to next page without being re-directed. How would I do this.

Comment: @davidthom42 Let's pretend that you want to send a `1`. Is that `1` coming from the user or the server? Now say that Page 2 receives `1`. What should happen next?

Comment: Discussion between Mike and OP [archived in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134254/discussion-on-question-by-davidthom42-how-to-get-ajax-to-post-on-second-page). If the number of comments exceeds more than 15, then it's a good indicator that it should be made as an answer. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I need I believe:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("button").click(function() {
var dataPoint = "chunk of data";
    ///////// AJAX //////// AJAX //////////
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'some_page_name.php',
            data: {dataPoint:dataPoint},
            success: function( response ){
                $('#success').html("Sent!!");
            }
        });
    ///////// AJAX //////// AJAX /////////

  });
```

And for your HTML Page:

```
<button>Click me</button>
<div id="success"></div>
```

Modify as needed.